# Multiple arrays stored in one Variable. [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I have multiple arrays stored in one variable each of them is size 1. I'm trying to combine all of them into one single array. I've used Buffered reader to read a csv file and then split it into an arraylist using the following method:

public static ArrayListcsvToArray(String csvData){
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

```
    if (csvData != null){
        String[] splitData = csvData.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++){
            if(!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                result.add(splitData[i].trim());
            }
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

The method splits each line of the csv into an arraylist of its own. I want to combine all elements at for example result.get(5) into an arraylist of their own.
Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Add some code and more explanation of what the input is what the output should be.

Comment: Do you have some code that you can show us?

Comment: so you want every word to go into a separate array list?

Comment: No the method splits the CSV file at the comma. this creates an arraylist containing 8 elements it does this 100 times creating 100 arraylists each containing 8 elements. I want to take a specific element for example the element at result.get(5) and combine them all from the 100 seperate arraylists into an arraylist of 100 elements.

Comment: So is 100 a known number, it wont be more than that? And are elements always going to be 8?

Comment: The size of the CSV won't change. so there will always be 100 lines containing 8 elements each.

Comment: See my answer below, it also gets rid of the limitation of 100 lines and 8 elements as it checks it dynamically. If that does not resolve the issue please comment. If it gives you the desired results remember to accept the answer and vote up :)

Comment: Your answer seems to have seperated each element in the arraylists into arraylists of their own. I want to take the 5th item from each array list and consolidate them into an arraylist containing the 5th item of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea is to have a parent ArrayList of ArrayList. Every time you call the function, pass along the reference to previous results so they can be consolidated. This is just one out of many ways this can be achieved, but should give you a starting point to optimize further.

```
// Initialize and provide dummy input.
int requiredIndex = 5;
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    csvToArray("some,column,data,with,seven,columns,only", results, requiredIndex);
    csvToArray("more,data,that,came, in, just, now , and is, longer", results, requiredIndex);
    csvToArray("a, short, line", results, requiredIndex);
    csvToArray("last, line, of, input, which, is, correct.", results, requiredIndex);
    System.out.println(results);
    // output : [columns, just, is]

// Update the method as below.
public static void csvToArray(String csvData, ArrayList<String> results, int index){
    if (csvData != null){
        String[] splitData = csvData.split(",");
        int wordCount = 0;
        if(splitData.length < index)
            return;
        for(int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++){
            if(!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                ArrayList<String> individualList = new ArrayList<String>();
                individualList.add(splitData[i].trim());
                if(wordCount == index)
                    results.add(splitData[i].trim());
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you might notice I have not placed any limitations on number of rows or the number of columns. This is to cater to wider scenarios but if not, you might initialize with limits so memory allocation is optimized.

Comment: Your answer seems to have seperated each element in the arraylists into arraylists of their own. I want to take the 5th item from each array list and consolidate them into an arraylist containing the 5th item of each line.

Comment: so you want only specifc index and not all? Rest of your results are not needed or can remain that way?

Comment: I want to create a single arraylist of the items at the 5th index.

Comment: Now the array will only contain items from the specified index.

Comment: This create 100 different arrays of size 1. i want to create a single array of size 100.

Comment: i think you are calling it in some different way as it creates one array. Let me edit the answer one more time to make it clear.

Comment: Yeah you were right I've changed the way its called and now it works. Thanks a lot Hassan you're a life saver :).

Answer (score 0):

You can add each arraylist to another arraylist,

```
    ArrayList allresults = new ArrayList();
    result = ArrayListcsvToArray(csvData);
    allresults.add(result);

    public static ArrayListcsvToArray(String csvData){ 
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

        if (csvData != null){
            String[] splitData = csvData.split(",");
            for(int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++){
                if(!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                    result.add(splitData[i].trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
```